# Compile g++ on XCode 5?

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, g++

I'm starting with OpenGL in c++, and I included GLUT and OpenGL frameworks on my project on XCode. When I try to compile and run my program as if it was a simple c++ program it gives me this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_glBegin", referenced from:
    display() in main.o
"_glClear", referenced from:
    display() in main.o
"_glClearColor", referenced from:
etc.
```

Using a simple c++ program, I don't get any of this errors. I searched the web and I found that I need to compile with g++ (specific for c++ lenguage), but I don't know how to do it. Any help?

Comment: This title is highly misleading, I was under the impression that you were trying to compile gcc/g++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `-framework OpenGL` to your compiler settings.